# Multiplication of 2 terms. How to get to the modulo term and the result? Fast and simple

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

$\left(x^{3}+x^{2}+1\right)\left(x^{2}+x+1\right)=x^{5}+x+1 \equiv x^{2}+1 \bmod x^{4}+x+1=0101$

I have this equation and I don't get how to get to the answers?

Is there a fast method to get to the result?

And I don't get the modulo part how do I come up to this myself?

Could someone explain me this simple and maybe a general way to approach things like this fast?

Comment: I don't understand what equation (or congruence) you are trying to solve.

Comment: From left to right.How to get the middle part especially

Comment: Are you taking coefficients modulo two?

Comment: I guess so? It's an equation in my script that I just don't get

Comment: I don't understand.  What modulus is the congruence with respect to?  Maybe it would help if you broke it down step by step instead of just writing it in this run-on sort of way.

Comment: We use the factors as the binary values

Comment: x^4 would be 100

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying.  Please edit your post for clarity.  It isn't true, for example, that $x^5+x+1\equiv x^2+1\pmod {x^4+x+1}$ which, I think, you are claiming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're taking coefficients modulo two; if not, you can clarify what you mean and I'll change my answer.

Multiply it out:
$$
(x^3+x^2+1)(x^2+x+1) = 1 + x + 2 x^2 + 2 x^3 + 2 x^4 + x^5
$$Take coefficients mod two:
$$
\to 1 + x + x^5
$$Now compute modulo $x^4+x+1$. This means $x^4+x+1=0$, or $x^4=x+1$, or $x^5=x^2+x$:
$$
\to 1+x+(x^2+x)\to 1+x^2
$$

Comment: Jesus thanks yeah seems like the best way to understand this. Thanks! Simple

Comment: But wait. How do I get the middle part? You are using the original equation mod x^4+x+1 ? Why x^4+x+1.

Comment: I want to know how to get from the first part to the second part so before my first = to the part after this =

Comment: *As I understand your question* you have polynomials with coefficients mod 2, which corresponds to binary representations of integers, which you are then taking modulo some polynomial. I am interpreting this as "compute two numbers modulo another one;" namely, $11\cdot 7\bmod 21$.

Comment: Isn't the term more like 13*7 mod 21 ?  And what about the getting to x^5+x+1 and x^2+1? In your way it seems like x^2+1 is just the answer. So in my equation it's the answer and and the congruence just means it's taken modulo now and with this congruent to the part before?

Comment: k how about now